# Can I invoke powershell with a command in a way that pushes that command in the history?

Tags: powershell

I am invoking the windows terminal with command line arguments to run processes automatically (multi-pane setup omitted for readability):

`wt -M new-tab -d . --title "Foo" powershell.exe -NoExit -Command somecalculation.exe`

However if the process finishes or gets aborted, I can't use arrow up + enter to rerun the process: I have to type somecalculation.exe and all its parameters once every time I use a fresh terminal. Many panes with different processes are involved, so being able to use the history would be great.

Is there a way to invoke powershell which allows me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What happens is you save the command to a varible. Then kick out the results of that varible.

```
wt -M new-tab -d . --title "Foo" powershell.exe -NoExit -Command "$result = cmd /c somecalculation.exe; $result | out-file C:\temp\results.txt"
```

Comment: Doing that gives me a `[Fehler 0x80070002 beim Start von '" $result | out-file C:\temp\results.txt"']`